# Zooming out of the google map glitchy

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps in my project. And I have a select field consisting of a country and it's counties. On changing the location with the select I zoom in to that location and draw a polygon on the map. It works fine when I am drawing a polygon for one location. 
But, if I select a country with, in this case 20 polygons that needs to be drawn and then zoom out from the map to be visible, the whole animation process becomes glitchy. I have tried to wrap the zooming into a Promise object and wait until it is finished and then center the map and draw polygons in hope it would help make it a smooth animation. Below I have the select onchange event, where depending on the value that was selected I zoom in or zoom out from the map and draw polygons. If the selected value was a county I zoom in to the map and draw polygon just for that county. If the country was selected I zoom out and draw polygons of all counties of that country:

```
        let regions = geodata;
        let center = MAP_CENTER;
        let zoomLevel = 7;

        if (select.value !== country) {
            const location = geodata.find(({ Name }) => Name.includes(select.value));
            regions = [location];
            center = { lat: Number(location.Lat), lng: Number(location.Lng) };
            zoomLevel = 9;
        }

        smoothZoomPromise(map, zoomLevel, map.getZoom()).then((googleMap) => {
            googleMap.panTo(center);
            if (!(select.value === country && polygons.state.arrayOfPolygons.length === geodata.length)) {
                drawRegions(googleMap, regions);
            }
        });
```

This is the **smoothZoomPromise** function:

```
const smoothZoomPromise = (map, wantedLevel, startingLevel) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (wantedLevel === startingLevel) {
            return resolve(map);
        }
        const smoothZoom = (googleMap, finishLevel, startLevel) => {
            if (finishLevel === startLevel) {
                return;
            }
            const current = startLevel > finishLevel ? startLevel - 1 : startLevel + 1;
            const z = google.maps.event.addListener(googleMap, 'zoom_changed', event => {
                google.maps.event.removeListener(z);
                smoothZoom(googleMap, finishLevel, current);
            })

            doZoom(googleMap, current, resolve, current === finishLevel);
        }

        smoothZoom(map, wantedLevel, startingLevel);
    });
}

const doZoom = (map, cnt, resolve, last) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        map.setZoom(cnt);
        if(last) {resolve(map)}
    }, 80);
}
```

And this is how I draw polygons:

```
export const polygons = {
    state: {
        arrayOfPolygons: []
    },
    clearState: function () {
        this.state.arrayOfPolygons.forEach(polygon => polygon.setMap(null));
        this.state.arrayOfPolygons = []
    }
};

export const drawRegions = (map, regions) => {
    polygons.clearState();
    regions.forEach(region => {
        const coords = region.Coordinates.map(item => ({
            lat: item[1], lng: item[0],
        }))

        // Construct the polygon.
        const color = colorMapper(getStatsData(region.Name));
        const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: coords,
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        polygon.setMap(map);
        polygons.state.arrayOfPolygons.push(polygon)
    })
}
```

But, like I mentioned, the problem that I have is that when I select a country and zoom out from 9 to 7 zoom level, and draw 20 polygons for it, the zooming out of the map becomes glitchy. Is there a way I can make this smooth and fix it?

I made an example [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-leakey-35mh9?file=/src/index.js). The only thing that is needed to have it working, is a valid **API_KEY** in `index.js`:

```
if (document.querySelector(".js-map")) {
  gmap.GMap(".js-map", "YOUR_API_KEY");
}
```

I would like to achieve the same transition as it is done [here](https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen&mid=%2Fm%2F09c7w0) with google maps. Where if you zoom all the way in, and then change location with select, the map is not rendered until it is zoomed out. How can I achieve that effect?

Comment: Code formatting (back ticks) should be used to include code within the text, not to just ruin the readability of your questions.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have removed them, hope it is more readable now

Comment: Sample data and a [mcve] might be what you are missing now.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have edited the question with a codesandbox example that includes sample data. Only thing needed there is a valid API_KEY for google maps. Hope it will help to understand the problem.

Comment: @Leff I'm investigating this issue, I'll get back to you soon. :)

Comment: @Leff I think the smoothZoom promise is what is causing this glitch, can you try this codesandbox and let me know if it is what you wanted? https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-khorana-syiq0?file=/src/selectBuilder.js

Comment: Also it looks like the covid website you linked implements it as follows: first, these actions are bound to the onZoomChanged event: debounce with 250 ms delay, and a different style is applied to the map depending on the initial and target zoom level. Then, setCenter() to the new location and finally setZoom() to the target zoom level, without using intermediate levels.

Comment: Note that there might be a CSS background or display property that avoids the flash when the tiles are loading too, so that missing tiles appear the same color as the normal background and water color of the map tiles style.

Comment: @evan thank you very much for making the effort and explaining the way it works on the covid map

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know if the above example helps or need a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to wrap the polygon drawing inside of a one-time `idle` listener, i.e:

```
smoothZoomPromise(map, zoomLevel, map.getZoom()).then((googleMap) => {
  googleMap.panTo(center);
  if (
    !(
      select.value === "Croatia" &&
      polygons.state.arrayOfPolygons.length === geodata.length
    )
  ) {

    //  ----|
    //      |
    //      v
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(googleMap, "idle", () => {
      drawRegions(googleMap, regions);
    });

  }
});
```

A sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-burnell-6oz64?file=/src/selectBuilder.js) -- you'll need to put your own api key in.

I think that's what google does anyways -- it's standard practice. You can check the different types of gmap events in action [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).